# Using an aspx file as the source of an audio tag prevents fast forwarding

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, html5-audio

I am trying to create a basic ASP.NET audio library, using an HTML5 audio tag and an ASPX file as the source of the audio. The problem is that when I use an ASPX file instead of using the mp3 file directly, the audio player does not allow to fast forward or back track, only pause, resume and restart the track.

The reason I am using an ASPX file as the source is so to not expose the audio file and let the ASPX file handle the authentication/authorization before transmitting the file. I am including the relevant code on the side of the ASPX page as well as the basic audio tag code I am using.

Maybe I am going about it wrong? Is there a better way to provide the mp3 file to the audio tag without exposing it? Should I look for a more robust audio player rather than try to use audio tag?

```
<audio controls preload="metadata" style="width: 100%;">
    <source src="FileDownload.aspx" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     Response.Clear();
     Response.ClearHeaders();
     Response.ClearContent();
     Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" sample.mp3");
     Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", 2000);
     Response.ContentType = "audio/mpeg";
     Response.Flush();
     Response.TransmitFile("C:\\temp\\sample.mp3");
     Response.End();
}
```

Comment: You need to support [range requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests) probably.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was indeed my problem. Adding Accept-Range to the header solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Mat J](https://stackoverflow.com/users/219933/mat-j) said, you have to use HTTP range requests as documented at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests